# Not displayed everything from content in GenericTile

Tags: sapui5

I am using OpenUI5, this is my code:

```
<GenericTile headerText="Header" subheader="Subheader" size="M" frameType="TwoByOne" press="press">
            <tileContent>
                <TileContent>
                    <content>
                        <Title text="Title" />
                        <NumericContent size="S" scale="M" value="{/para2}" valueColor="Error" indicator="Up" />
                        <Text text="Text1" />
                        <Link text="Link" press="viewMore" />
                    </content>
                </TileContent>
            </tileContent>
        </GenericTile>
```

and all what I see is:
[image]

Why it doesn't display `NumericContent`, `Text` and `Title`?
As I noticed it only displaying the last element of content - it depends on order these elements.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add multiple control inside the content of sap.m.TileContent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53394804/how-to-add-multiple-control-inside-the-content-of-sap-m-tilecontent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53394804/how-to-add-multiple-control-inside-the-content-of-sap-m-tilecontent/53395295#53395295).

**In short:**
This is happening because content in [sap.m.TileContent aggregations](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.TileContent/aggregations) has the cardinality of 0..1 where 0 is the minimum cardinality, and 1 is the maximum cardinality. This means you can only have a single item inside the content property and so the Tile will only display the last element defined in your view.

You can work around this issue by adding a [Sap.m.VBox](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.VBox) inside your tile content like this:

```
<GenericTile subheader="Subheader" frameType="TwoByOne" press="press">
   <TileContent>
      <content>
         <VBox>
            <Title text="Title"/>
            <NumericContent scale="M" value="{/para2}" valueColor="Error" indicator="Up"/>
            <Text text="Text1"/>
            <Link text="Link" press="viewMore"/>
         </VBox>
      </content>
   </TileContent>
</GenericTile>
```

**Although I really would advise you not to do this** but instead use the properties on [sap.m.TileContent](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.TileContent/controlProperties) such as **footer** and **unit** where you can insert text and number details to your Tile.